# Internal Microphone not working on new kernel update

Tags: sound, kernel, pulseaudio, microphone, amd-ryzen

My Internal microphone on laptop is not being detected after updating to the new kernel `5.8.0-45-generic`. However it was working on previous kernel version `5.8.0-36-generic`. I'm using Lenovo IdeaPad 5 with Ryzen 7. I tried all previous solutions but no luck. Most of them were for intel based laptops so couldn't edit the source files. Also, pulseaudio manager wasn't helpful. I tried reverting back to the `5.8.0-36-generic` and `5.8.0-40-generic` the problem still remains plus touchpad and brightness slider stops working.

Comment: See if you can load a 5.4 kernel and that might work.

Comment: Tried using 5.10 oem and it worked. But I'm little bit concerned about the hwe support.

Comment: Same here, but using a msi gl63 8RC and ubuntu 20.04: updating to 5.13.0-41 makes the micro not usable and rollback to 5.13.0-40 makes it working consistently with fresh reboots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced this yesterday as well on mainline kernels 5.11.6, 5.11.7, and 5.11.8. No microphone hardware is detected.

Rolled back to 5.11.5 for now and everything's fine. Boo.